# Error installing libjpeg on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: python-2.7, python-imaging-library, libjpeg

While installing `libjpeg` on PIL, Python 2.7

```
 sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev
```

i'm getting an error:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
    libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg8-dev libjpeg-dev
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main libjpeg-turbo8-dev i386 1.2.1-0ubuntu2.13.04.1
    404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main libjpeg-turbo8-dev i386 1.2.1-0ubuntu2.13.04.1
    404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo8-dev_1.2.1-0ubuntu2.13.04.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Update 1:

```
sudo apt-get update

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main i386 Packages
```

404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

Comment: What happens when you run apt-get update?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the ip/address of Ubuntu libs repositories changed, 
because the system already after "End Of Life", so you need to manually edit repositories list that used by apt-get.

you can see a hint for it [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/ubuntu-13-04-apt-get-update-problems-4175460316/) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release).

in my case, i preferred to upgrade to 14.04. it's a LTS version, so next time I should meet this problem will be after 5 years of usage.

to upgrade yours look [this site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502905/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-13-10-end-of-life-to-ubuntu-14-04).
for now (September 2014) I needed to upgrade it twice.
once from 13.04 to 13.10 and next to 14.04.

note: the first step was suggested to do by "sudo update-manager -d", but this doesn't work because of the same repositories problem. so I used "sudo do-release-upgrade"